# Using VBA to output user data to a shell command

Tags: vba, shell, cmd

I hope you can help.

I'm trying to create a form in excel using VBA that users put a value in and when the command button is clicked, it outputs that value into a shell command.

The command I'm using is;

SC \"*computer name on network*" query "*service on that computer that I'm querying*"

I've tried alot of things to try and get the textbox value to be inputted into the middle of the shell command but to no success.

The shell command would need to be like below;

SC \" *textbox1.value*" query "*textbox2.value*"

Any help would be massively appreciated.

The below if basically what I'm trying to accomplish;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 

    Dim destination As String 
    destination = destination.Value 
    Shell "cmd.exe /c" "ping " destination 

End Sub
```

Comment: "I've tried a lot of things": So, what have you tried, and why did they not work? here is your current code so we can have a look at your tries and provide guidance based on that. No one here is going to write the code from scratch.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, my apologies as I'm new to this and not sure of the correct terminology when asking for assistance. The below if basically what I'm trying to accomplish;                        
                                                                       Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 

Dim destination As String

destination = destination.Value

 

Shell "cmd.exe /c" "ping " destination

 

End Sub

Comment: With the goal being that thd user inputs a destination into the destination field (in this scenario being Google.com) then once the user presses the command button it loads Command prompt and runs the command 'ping Google.com'

Comment: But further command would require multiple inputs such as SC \\"user input" stop "user input"

Comment: `Shell "cmd.exe /c ping " & destination`